# How to simplify variable assignment by way of IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the simple Python 3 expression:

```
if a:
    b = a
else:
    print('error')
```

However in my case, it just so happens that 'a' is equal to a very verbose but necessary regex search command (not relevant here.) Can I simplify the above code so that:

1) I don't need to assign a value to 'a'.

2) I don't need to state the value of 'a' twice in the expression.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `b = a or b`. But I would assign the result to a temporary variable.

Comment: [Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4978738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
b = a or False
if b:
    print("okay")
else:
    print("error")
```

where `False` can be any special value you can set yourself that can be used as a default value for `b` if `a` is falsy (provided that the condition of the `if` changes if the default value changes).

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> def check(rgx, s):
>>>   b = re.search(rgx, s) or False
>>>   if b:
>>>     print("okay")
>>>     return b
>>>   else:
>>>     print("error")
>>> 
>>> check('\W', 'Hello, world!')
okay
<re.Match object; span=(5, 6), match=','>
>>> check('\d', 'Hello, world!')
error
```

Comment: I think it should be 'or b', to keep the old value of b.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich won't `b = a or b` raise a `NameError` for the `b` in the RHS?

Comment: This answer is great for my original question but I neglected to mention I want to keep it in an 'if statement' format, so that I can use the 'else' functionality to raise an error. Sorry - have made an edit

Comment: @freddieaj In this case, you can use your `if` with `b`.

Comment: @MrGeek: I was assuming that b already had a value, otherwise his if statement would lead to the situation that further on, b would either have a value or be a NameError, and that would be bad. But he planned on using else:, so maybe it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.8, [named assignments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) will be introduced that let you do:

```
if a := complicated_expression: 
    b = a
```

The suggestion

```
b = a or b
```

is valid, but requires that `b` is assigned a value beforehand. Also it just works if the condition only checks for the truthiness of `a`
For a strict one-liner with an arbitrary condition, you can always use the singleton generator-trick:

```
b = next((a for a in (complex_expression for _ in '_') if condition(a)), None)
```

But that should be considered purely academical.

Comment: But even then, you're assigning to a temporary variable. := just saves a line.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That's true, but the asumption is that this line is what the OP wants to save.

Comment: Thanks for this - great answer but unfortunately not usable currently